# Check for duplicate of encrypted data

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, hash

I was hoping to get some advice on a particular task I'm trying to implement.

I have a table that stores secure data and returns an ID as a representation of that data.  No problems there.  So, for example, if a social security number is stored, the code generates a representational ID and stores the social security number in an encrypted fashion in the table.  The encryption is done using envelope encryption.

Here's my issue.  Every time a new value comes in, I don't want to create a new ID if the data already exists.  I need to check to see if the value already exists and, if so, return the existing ID.  The problem I have is that the encrypted value is different each time and I certainly can't decrypt every value in the database to check for a duplicate.  I could create a one way hash and store that as well but, if I do, I would need to salt it for security purposes and the hash will be different every time.

So I'm hoping to get advice/recommendations on how to achieve this?  How to check for duplicates when the value is stored in an encrypted fashion.

Thank you!

Comment: stackoverflow really isn't a forum. You should ask about a specific problem, with code you've tried, and results that are expected and wrong. Otherwise, this is way too broad to cover.

Comment: Post this in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ that is more of a design and discussion for software

Comment: @Ice76 thank you for the info!  Just posted there and will close this post.

Comment: Depends how it's encrypted, if it's hashed it's simple. if it's 2 way its not.  Use a salted sha512 with a couple rounds of hashing on it like a password.  2-way encryption is insecure by its very nature unless you do asymmetric encryption.  If the key to decrypt it exists on the server, well, it's not very secure then.  If it was me I would use a combination of sha512 and Open SSL, with only one key ( the one to encrypt it ) on the web server.  Then a hacker is brute forcing it at best. if it's AES, all they need to do is find the key you used to encrypt it.

Comment: Store a hash of the encrypted value and use that to determine if it already exists. Don't use a salted hash unless you *really* want to throw away your indexes.